# dropdown does not go on top of items in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the current code:
HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-controller="dropDown">
    Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ selectedType }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownCountry">
        <li ng-repeat="iType in itemTypes">
            <a>{{iType}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Language:
    <input type="text" name="language" class="input-xsmall" ng-model="projectName.language" placeholder="Item Language" />
</div>
```

the dropdown is part of a tab control.

and the js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('dropDown', function($scope)
{
   $scope.selectedType = 'Custom Report';
   $scope.itemTypes=[
        'Custom Report',
        'Form',
        'Personalization'
   ];
});
```

[here is the full code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JNtvS2B0VbTFIAoPI9MN?p=preview)

But when I open the dropdown, instead of going on top of items, it goes under, so i get this picture:

[image]

so i have 2 question:

1. Main question is how to make the dropdown go on top of the other items?
2. As you can see the dropdown is opened in the corner. how can i make it align to the button that opens it?

Comment: @downvoter, please comment so i know what is wrong

Comment: Your tab-content class is set to `overflow:auto`. Remove it, and the dropdown shows normally. Just position the dropdown into a div and modify its style. Something like that: http://plnkr.co/edit/6cMYMmWJuH2li6qibZZ5?p=preview

Comment: @PatrickG tnx, but why aren't you write it in an answer?
anyway, that helped me with the second problem, but i haven't understand what are you saying regarding 'overflow:auto'. what class should i choose?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if this is what you were looking for. You'll get the detailed answer in a sec.

Comment: Took me a little longer to write a detailed answer. I hope it is a little more enlightening than my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already got the answer for the second question from here http://plnkr.co/edit/6cMYMmWJuH2li6qibZZ5?p=preview (putting a div element around the dropdown menu, to align it relatively to the opener link):

```
<div style="position:relative;display:inline;">
  <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ selectedType }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ria-labelledby="dropdownCountry">                 
    <li ng-repeat="iType in itemTypes">
      <a>{{iType}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There is still your first question, regarding the dropdown menu being displayed underneath the other objects. From your link we can see, that the `tab-content` class has the value: `overflow:auto`. Now you can either just put the new styles on the element itself (not really suggested)

```
<div class="tab-content" style="overflow:visible;">...</div>
```

or you can just modify your CSS file (remove this line or set to `visible`):

```
.tab-content{overflow:auto;}
```

Line taken from `bootstrap-combined.min.css`, line 608.

You could also create a new CSS file, in which you overwrite the value just for that particular case and leave all the other tab-content classes preformatted by bootstrap (by adding another class to that specific element and styling only that special class with `overflow:visible;`).

Comment: first of all, thank you.
i'm trying to change the 'style' on the 'div', the 'ul', and even the 'li' but it doesn't seems to do the trick... anything i'm missing?

Comment: Could you create another plunker of what you tried? Maybe I can help you out with that.

Comment: Actually you don't have to change the UL and LI to solve your problem. Just follow this guide right here: http://plnkr.co/edit/P57JDwTdBYGxHJLpJAY1?p=preview. I have added a `<style>` block to the `head` section.